# Difficult aggregation and summarize of DataFrame in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : [1, 2, 3, 22, 3],
                    "Nazwa" : ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "cc"], 
                    "L" : [11, 22, 33, 55, 44]})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOrww.png)

And finally, I would like to group this DF by "Nazwa" and then aggregate (sum) by "ID". Then I would like to have for each value in "Nazwa" summarized "ID" and the biggest values from "L" for this "Nazwa". It could be not enough understandable so below I put the table which I would like to achieve based on the above table data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqhdt.png)

Comment: BTW, you should embed the image (but better yet - copy paste your table to the question and highlight it as code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the group by with [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), such that:

```
data.groupby(['Nazwa']).agg({'ID':'sum','L':'max'}).reset_index()
```

desired result:

```
   Nazwa    ID  L
0   aa      1   11
1   bb      2   22
2   cc      6   44
3   dd     22   55
```

and if the order of the columns are critical:

```
data.groupby(['Nazwa']).agg({'ID':'sum','L':'max'}).reset_index()[['ID','Nazwa','L']]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! But how can I albo remove index? Because currently I have ID and Nazwa in index and ID and L i columns, reset_index() does not work ?

Comment: simply do: data.index = data['ID''] and then drop the column ['ID'].

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much I accepted your answer adhg!

Comment: @rumor154 pleasure. Welcome to SO